# Image size in the center changed with gridlayoutmanager 3 spancount

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imageview, android-glide, gridlayoutmanager

I have recyclerview with gridlayoutmanager with spancount of 3. Imageview size in center is different from others. I have tried all scaletypes but nothing helps.

```
private fun initRecycler(){
            val gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context,3)
            binding.rvWallpapers.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
            mainAdapter = MainAdapter(context, this)
            binding.rvWallpapers.addOnScrolledToEnd {
                binding.skvLoadingEnd.isVisible = true
                initCategory()
            }
            binding.rvWallpapers.adapter = mainAdapter
        }
    

Glide.with(context).load(sizesModel.url).centerCrop().listener(object :RequestListener<Drawable?>{
            override fun onLoadFailed(
                e: GlideException?,
                model: Any?,
                target: Target<Drawable?>?,
                isFirstResource: Boolean
            ): Boolean {
                return false
            }

        override fun onResourceReady(
            resource: Drawable?,
            model: Any?,
            target: Target<Drawable?>?,
            dataSource: DataSource?,
            isFirstResource: Boolean
        ): Boolean {
            Log.d("sizes", "width: "+binding.ivWallpapers.width.toString()+"height: "+binding.ivWallpapers.height.toString())
            binding.skvLoading.isVisible = false
            return false
        }
    }).into(binding.ivWallpapers)
```

Here is log:

```
D/sizes: width: 465height: 930
D/sizes: width: 470height: 940
D/sizes: width: 465height: 930
D/sizes: width: 465height: 930
D/sizes: width: 470height: 940
D/sizes: width: 465height: 930
D/sizes: width: 465height: 930
D/sizes: width: 470height: 940
D/sizes: width: 465height: 930
```

imageview in center has 470 width and 940 height, however imageviews from left side and right side have 465 width and 930 height

Comment: I will note that both sizes of the _ImageViews_ have the same aspect ratio of "2". It may help if you would post your adapter code to show where the view holders are created.

Comment: @Cheticamp https://pastebin.com/jweE38Dm - adapter code
https://pastebin.com/5txsa1HT - xml code

Comment: I don't know if the following will work, but it is an easy try: Change `wrap_content` to `match_parent` for the height of the _ConstraintLayout_.